# Reusing view controller inside of scroll view. Swift iOS8 development

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

Using Swift for iOS8 in Xcode6, I need to create a scroll view that will scroll through dynamically created cards. The cards contain their own unique images, text, and button functions but share an identical layout. I'm having trouble understanding how to create a re-usable view controller in the storyboard from which I can build each card and then embed them all into a scroll view container so that I can slide through them one at a time.

Normally I like to ask more specific questions on Stack Overflow but after hours of research I'm at a loss; your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for custom container view controller.

If doing this programmatically, you call `addChildViewController` on the parent controller (thereby adding the child view controller into the view controller hierarchy), do all of the configuration of the child's view (including adding it to the parent controller's view hierarchy) and then at the very end, call `didMoveToParentViewController` on the child:

```
let child = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardIdForChildScene")
addChild(child)
child.view.frame = .zero
scrollView.addSubview(child.view)
child.didMove(toParent: self)
```

When removing programmatically, you reverse this process, calling `willMoveToParentViewController:nil` on the child, remove the child view from its superview, and when all done, call `removeFromParentViewController`:

```
child.willMove(toParent: nil)
child.view.removeFromSuperview()
child.removeFromParent()
```

If doing this in Interface Builder, it's much easier, just drag the "Container View" from the "Object Library" onto your parent view controller's scene:

[image: container view]

For more information on how to do this, see [Implementing a Custom Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW12) in the *View Controller Programming Guide.* For a discussion on why it's important to do these containment calls in order to keep the view controller hierarchy synchronized with the view hierarchy, see WWDC 2011 video [Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102).

---

The above is for Swift 4. For early Swift versions, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26430367/3).

Comment: Thank you! I'm currently looking through your references and digesting all of this information. From the looks of it though I should be able to create a ViewController in the storyboard that has the layout I want, connect that ViewController to a container view inside of a ScrollView and then programatically duplicate that original ViewController with unique properties to create all of my cards?

Comment: If doing it programmatically, you would "instantiate" the new child view controllers (like shown above), not "duplicate".

Comment: Right! Sorry, misspoke. I completely understand the concept of OOP and instantiation an instance of a class to make multiple objects based off that class. The trouble I'm having is understanding how to create that class in the storyboard and then instantiate multiple instances of that to fill my scroll view. It definitely looks like you've set me on the right path. I'm watching the video you linked now to prep myself then I'll try implementing it.

Comment: I'm sure you'll figure it out, but just create a scene in IB for your new "card" view. Give this scene a custom storyboard id. And specify your child view controller as the base class for this new scene. Now, when you `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, it creates an instance of your new view controller class and its view and outlets will be just like you laid it out in IB. Just add this newly instantiated scene as a child as shown above. Just repeat that process for each child view your add to your scroll view. I think when you dig into this, it will all "fall into place."